# Get ItemId of newly received email while getting notification through “StreamingSubscription” of EWS Exchange Server.

Tags: c#, email, outlook, notifications, exchangewebservices

I am creating a tool (a windows application) to receive notification of the mail and once I receive the notification that a new mail has been received then I can choose to read this mail or ignore it.

I am able to get stream notification but it only says that a new mail has been received now my requirement is that display a message that new mail has been received from “X Person(sender)” and use can choose that he/she want to read or ignore it.

Right now after getting notification I hit the email server and get all the unread mails and then fetching last unread mail from that list but it is not right approach suppose 2-3 mails received at same time then it will get confused that which email has to fetch.

Below is the code I am using for stream notification

```
void SetStreamingNotifications(ExchangeService service)
        {            
            StreamingSubscription streamingsubscription = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
                new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
                EventType.NewMail,
                EventType.Created,
                EventType.Deleted);

            StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 1);

            connection.AddSubscription(streamingsubscription);
            // Delegate event handlers. 
            connection.OnNotificationEvent +=
                new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.NotificationEventDelegate(OnEvent);
            connection.OnSubscriptionError +=
                new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.SubscriptionErrorDelegate(OnError);
            connection.OnDisconnect +=
                new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.SubscriptionErrorDelegate(OnDisconnect);
            connection.Open();          
        }
```

**Now my question is that how can I get the ItemId of newly received email as soon as I get notification through “StreamingSubscription” that a new mail has been received.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ItemId is returned in the ItemEvent class (which comes as part of the SOAP notification) eg

```
        switch (notification.EventType) 
    { 
        case EventType.NewMail: 
            Console.WriteLine("\n————-Mail created:————-"); 
            break; 
        case EventType.Created: 
            Console.WriteLine("\n————-Item or folder created:————-"); 
            break; 
        case EventType.Deleted: 
            Console.WriteLine("\n————-Item or folder deleted:————-"); 
            break; 
    } 
    // Display the notification identifier. 
    if (notification is ItemEvent) 
    { 
        // The NotificationEvent for an e-mail message is an ItemEvent. 
        ItemEvent itemEvent = (ItemEvent)notification; 
        Console.WriteLine("\nItemId: " + itemEvent.ItemId.UniqueId); 
    }
```

There are a number of good sample that use this like https://ewsstreaming.codeplex.com/